# Plugins in distributed/clustered web application

Tags: google-app-engine, plugins, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am developing plugin based web-application, where I am using web application to install its plugins. The flow is like this.

- User uploads zip file(plugin)
- Web app unzips and move jsps to web-inf & jar (contains controllers, blogic, dao) to lib folder.

Now the question is, if I deploy this application in cloud computing like amazon aws or google app engine, how we can make sure that this plugins will be available for all the instances.

I think same problem will come even if I use in-house servers with distributed load.

I am thinking to have master instance which will know about all the new instances created. If any plugin is there we need to install on master and it should have some mechanism to propagate changes to child. Which again I doubt whether it is possible for gae.

Comment: How will you guard against malicious code ?  Appengine won't allow you to write to the filesystem, so classes will need to be loaded from GCS or the datastore.  Application code deployed and accessible by the network is instantly accessible by all appengine instances, so with appengine you don't have any issues with updating services.  I just wouldn't do what you propose - that is running code from untrusted sources.

Comment: I am looking into some sandboxing techniques, to prevent that still I am not sure how much security I can achieve. You are suggesting to load the plugins from shared n/w locations?

Comment: For appengine you would be looking for a sandbaox inside the sandbox, that deals with multitenancy, if your using the datastore.  Not sure what you would need to do for mysql.  For appengine a shared location would be the datastore or google cloud storage.  It could be somewhere else but latencies will increase for load times the further you move from googles infrastructure.  I am not sure you can even load classes in java from other sources on appengine. You would need investigate if thats even possible.

Comment: What about other environments like local distributed servers & aws? any solution for those?

Comment: In AWS you are looking at virtual machines. You would probably deploy the plugins in the same way you deploy the base application.